# Replace a value in a string using another Map in scala

Tags: json, string, scala

I have a map of replacements

```
val replacements = Map( "123" -> "d", "234" -> "x", "345" -> "mx")
```

I would like to replace only one occurrences in the string i.e value of "name" in "session" with the corresponding value from replacements map.

String pattern is fixed : "name" will always be in "session"

```scala
val str = "{"section":[{"data":"xyz","session":"{\"**name**\":234}","data2":"234"}]}"

result =  "{"section":[{"data":"xyz","session":"{\"**name**\":x}","data2":"234"}]}"
```

234 of name is replaced by x but 234 of data2 remained same

I tried using `jsonMap = JsonUtils.jsonStrToMap(str)` but it does not work with nested jsonstring maps.

I am new to using scala regex for find and replace.

Comment: Show us the code you used, without this we cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straight forward approach would be to iterate over the `replacements` map, and replace every usage of the key, with its value in map entries:

```scala
replacements.foldLeft(str) { 
  case (updatingString, (key, replacement)) => updatingString.replaceAll(key, replacement)
}
```

Comment: That will replace the elements i don't want to replace as well. I only want to replace "name" in "session"

Comment: @Muskaan "Replace a value in a string using another Map in scala". Try to fix your question title and content first!